# Adobe Cloud Deploy: Package Dependencies are not being Imported

Tags: deployment, cloud, adobe, aem

So I'm using the AIO command line to deploy UI.APPS to an RDE.  Example deploy command:

**aio aem:rde:install ui.apps/target/x-xxxxxxxx-com.ui.apps-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip**

I'm getting this error when I deploy:

deploy staged for content-package x-xxxxxxx-com.ui.apps-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip on author,publish - done by C6581E4564C940E80A495E94@32ec1f6163674611495c17.e at 2023-09-09T21:35:52.965Z
Logs:

> The analyser found the following errors for author and publish :
> [api-regions-exportsimports] com.adobe.aem.temp:com.xx.aem.x-therapeutics-com.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: Bundle com.xx.aem.x-therapeutics-com.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT is importing package(s) com.adobe.acs.commons.models.injectors.annotation in start level 20 but no bundle is exporting these for that start level.

This usually means that a dependent project (Core) has an import that won't resolve.

QUESTION:  Is there a setting in the POM to address this?  EXPORT PACKAGE?

I see some Adobe documentation that explains this error:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/archetype/build-analyzer-maven-plugin.html?lang=en#

I tried adding in the EXPORT Package parameter but that's not working.

Comment: Have you tried deploying .all package instead ui.apps? because it seems like in ui.apps it has dependency with code bundle.